# How can I use a function defined in a controller in rails in a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, rubygems

I have an API function defined in my rails controller, and another to my database that I create using scaffold.
`

```
  def function
    @results = HTTParty.get( $baseurl + "/extention", :headers => {
      $apikey => $apivalue,
      "Content-Type" => "application/json"
    })
    render json: @results.body
  end
```

`

I have defined a rake task that is executed with clockwork but to make it work in the current development environment I had to use httparty to call it internally and work with the received hash.
`

```
  def rake_function
    @results = HTTParty.get("http://localhost:3000/controller/extension/")
    return @results.parsed_response
  end
```

`In addition, my task makes a post and a put when the execution is finished and I must also use a httparty for that.`

```
    if (!datExist)
        @response = HTTParty.post("http://localhost:3000/controller/extension/",
        body: eodData
        )
    else (datExist)
        checkId = dbData.select {|x| x["date_time"] == yesterday}
        id = checkId[0]["id"].to_s
        @response = HTTParty.put("http://localhost:3000/controller/extension/" + id,
        body: eodData
        )
    end
```

`

I know it's not the optimal way so I would like to be able to execute the function already defined in my controllers in my rake task

Comment: I would consider doing calls to external APIs in a controller a code smell. Just move the API calls in a proper model. And then call this class from your controller and/or Rake task.

Comment: @spickermann I would argue that HTTP calls don't belong in a model either as they also typically have a crazy amount of responsibilites/power in Rails even without a single line of code. Instead that should be done by a class (or classes) that is the only one that knows about the external API and just has that responsibility. Having a model that represents the data from the API in your application is a good idea though.

Answer (score 1):

### You don't.

The only public methods of your controller should be the "actions" that are called by the Rails router when it responds to HTTP requests.

Controllers are Rack applications and have a hard dependency on a incoming HTTP request - they just don't work outside of that context like in Rake task and using your controllers as a junk drawer leads to the "Fat Controller" anti-pattern.

Controllers already have tons of responsibilites - they are basically stiching your entire application together by passing user input to models and models to views. Don't give them more jobs to do.

Its a very easy problem to avoid by simply moving your API calls into their own class. One way of designing this is through client classes which are just resposible for communicating with the API:

```ruby
class MyApiClient
  include HTTParty
  format :json
  base_url $baseurl # Code smell - avoid the use of globals
  attr_reader :api_key, :api_value

  def initalize(api_key:, api_value:)
    @api_key = api_key
    @api_value = api_value
  end

  def get_extension
    # I don't get why you think you need to dynamically set the header key
    self.class.get('extension', headers: { api_key => api_value })
  end
end
```

This lets you simply re-use the code between your controller and rake task and isolates the code touching the application boundy which avoids creating a tight coupling between your application and the external collaborator.

HTTParty also really shines when you actually use it for object oriented and not proceedural code.

Comment: I agree with converting the API call into a class that is inherited by the controller, this way I can call the class in both the rake task and the controller, but that brings me to the second question, how do I query the database created with scaffold if these are also stored natively in the controller without using httparty? As I said in the post, I am not only querying via httparty a controller made for my front-end to query the API, I am also querying a "local" database where the information I do operations on is stored.

I clarify, the API I query is only enabled by the creator to do GET

Comment: No - you got it all wrong. This NOT a class inherited by the controller. Its a standalone class that you initialize and call from the controller. Inheritance doesn't remove responsibilities from a class. It just moves them up the inheritance chain.

Comment: How you query the DB is a totally different question. If it's in the same application as the rake task you just do it through your models. But I have no idea what you mean by the rest as "stored natively in the controller" is gibberish.